# Correcting for Noise in Multiple Geographic Sensor Readings

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, geolocation, sensors, noise

Given a list of geocoded locations with an unknown error-value and a database of less noisy public corrections nearer the true location (*most* of which are reliable), how should I design an algorithm to take all the corrections into account to approximate the true location most accurately?

Both the stationary coordinates and the sensor readings are noisy, so it is similar to a geographic check-in problem. It reminds me of a known problem with multiple noisy sensors, where you model the noise and calculate the most probable value, but I don't recall the solution.

All coordinates are stored as the `geography::POINT` type in SQL Server 2008, so an efficient solution for that platform would be most useful.

---

**Clarification:** Coordinates are *not* temporal. Each reading comes from a unique sensor with no repeat measurements.

Answer (score 2):

Alhtough I am not sure how to implement that in SQL Server 2008 a good algorithm could be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter (see http://www.developerstation.org/2011/09/kalman-filter-for-dummies-tutorials.html).

For an implementation it could be helpful to use the spatial index from SQL Server - see for example http://blogs.msdn.com/b/isaac/archive/2007/05/16/sql-server-spatial-support-an-introduction.aspx

Another interesting resource regargind spatial support in SQL Server is http://www.jasonfollas.com/blog/archive/2008/03/14/sql-server-2008-spatial-data-part-1.aspx

Although in C some application of a kalman filter see http://interactive-matter.eu/2009/12/filtering-sensor-data-with-a-kalman-filter/

**EDIT - as per comment:**

Depending on the requirements it could make more sense to use a modified version of Kalman filtering which not only takes white noise into account but also considers time-correlated errors - see for example http://hss.ulb.uni-bonn.de/2011/2605/2605.pdf

**EDIT 2 - after the Clarification from OP:**

In your scenario there is nothing to somehow "guess" an error except the less noisy public location... you could use any noise aware statistical algorithm... you could even select the 3 or 5 nearest coordinates (see the link regarding spatial support) and correct your measurement for example similar to a magnetic wand... another option would be to apply an error-correction by weighting the differences similar to triangulation etc.

**EDIT 3 - after comment from OP:**

One such algorithm is the Minimum-Weight-Triangulation of point sets... see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-weight_triangulation and http://code.google.com/p/minimum-weight-triangulator/

Comment: Kalman filter is the filter I had in mind, thanks. It works well for continuous measurement of velocity or acceleration by a few sensors, but will it work for hundreds of noisy, static-time readings made by different sensors with unknown errors?

Comment: Unfortunately my correction coordinates are not a time-series (I have added a clarification). The cited paper refers to a "static time series", which is a series of measurements done from a static GPS receiver. In this case, multiple independent sensors have each "checked in" once (and only once) at, or on the boundary of, the desired location.

Comment: in your scenario there is not much to use for error correction... which means you could basically use "any algorithm"... see my EDIT 2 above

Comment: You're right. What would make an appropriate triangulation algorithm for many points, some of which are outliers? I.e. "polyangulation".